# Know of a web app that prompts you for upcoming week's calendar tasks for all roles in life?

Tags: webapp-rec

15 years ago I had a program by Lotus?, called Scheduler I believe that was on an old Compaq.  It had a very cool *wizard* that was based on Coveys "7 Habits of Highly Effective People" and would allow you to define all the roles in your life and even create mission statements and do other cool things.  It was a straight-forward calendar program that was quite good and had a good user interface.  It had some built in functionality that I quite liked, which prompted you on Sunday, or a day of your choosing, to consider upcoming tasks for each role in your life, and prioritize your activities as you build your schedule for the upcoming week.

My question is "Has anyone seen an online web-app that has this sort of functionality?"  I am OK with using Google calendar, but would really like to hear if anyone has come across something that does some of the things my obsolete and no longer available program used to do.  It doesn't have to be integrated with a calendar, but that would be even better.

I notice that it says up top that my question appears subjective and is likely to be closed.  I hope not.  I believe this is the right forum for this question, and it is one I have been trying to find an answer to for years, to replace the functionality of this older desktop program.

Comment: I disagree with the rationale for closing this question and downvoting it.  I was looking for a specific type of software, and someone posted exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I also find it ironic that you closed it as not being "constructive", yet the prime function of the software is to increase productivity.  :c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across some of these web apps which are based on Coveys `7 Habits of Highly Effective People` . Haven't tried it myself though.

[PlanPlus Online Planner](http://www.franklincoveysoftware.com/individual/individual-products)

[FractalPlanner](http://www.fractalplanner.com/)

Comment: You are amazing!  I really have done many searches in the past, and there was nothing at their site, or anything similar to be found elsewhere.  Excellent.  The first link has the exact same concept, and it's from the same people.  Thanks.  The second site you gave looks very interesting too.  If I could vote you up I would.  I will when I can.

Comment: Glad I could be of help! :)